# Mapping windows timezone and IANA for 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time'

Tags: c#, timezone

I found that the mapping of windows timezone of 'Mid-Atlantic Standard Time' with IANA are "Etc/GMT+2" and "Etc/GMT+1"

from real data, I found that:
27-March-2011 at 3:00:00AM  to 25-Sep-2011 at 12:59:59AM would be Etc/GMT+1
25-Sep-2011 at 1:00:00AM to 25-March-2012 at 2:59:59AM would be Etc/GMT+2

This is the code I use to prove that the mapping is right:

```
var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
int currYear = currentDateTime.Year;

using(var database = Common.Patterns.TimeZoneInfo.Database.IANA.OpenInMemroyReadOnlyDatabase())
{
       var winTimeZone = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mid-Atlantic Standard Time");
       var commonTimeZoneSG = Zone.FindZone(database, "Atlantic/South_Georgia", ZoneNameTypes.IANATZName);
       var commonTimeZoneNoronho = Zone.FindZone(database, "America/Noronha", ZoneNameTypes.IANATZName);
       var commonTimeZoneGMT2 = Zone.FindZone(database, "Etc/GMT+2", ZoneNameTypes.IANATZName);
       var commonTimeZoneGMT1 = Zone.FindZone(database, "Etc/GMT+1", ZoneNameTypes.IANATZName);

for (int nMonth = 1; nMonth <= 12; ++nMonth)
{
    int nbrDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(currYear, nMonth);

    for (int nDay = 1; nDay <= nbrDays; ++nDay)
    {
        var currDateTime = new DateTime(currYear, nMonth, nDay, 11, 30, 09);
            //September 30 - March 24
            if(winTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(currDateTime) == commonTimeZoneSG.DetermineUTCOffset(currDateTime).Value)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(winTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(currDateTime) == commonTimeZoneNoronho.DetermineUTCOffset(currDateTime).Value)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(winTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(currDateTime) == commonTimeZoneGMT2.DetermineUTCOffset(currDateTime).Value)
            {
                break;
            }
            //March 25 - September 29
            if(winTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(currDateTime) == commonTimeZoneGMT1.DetermineUTCOffset(currDateTime).Value)
            {
                break;
            } 
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("not mappable for {0}",currDateTime));
                break;                                                                      
            }
    }

}
```

}

This is the transition rule I found:

```
System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mid-Atlantic Standard Time").GetAdjustmentRules().Dump();
```

I cant seem to relate the transition start and end rules that I found with the real data.
It says that it starts at 2AM but my real data is 3AM and ends at 1AM.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Might be helpful: [Unmappable Windows Time Zone (Mid-Atlantic Standard Time)](http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/extended-windows-olson-zid-mapping#TOC-Unmappable-Windows-Time-Zone-Mid-Atlantic-Standard-Time-)

Comment: no, i already got the mapping. I just dont understand the C# GetAdjustmentRules for transition time start and end.

Comment: What library are you using for your IANA database?  I can't find one that has this particular API.